# How to save a specific data from a text file and save that resultant data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am trying to read a text file and collect some information from the text.
For Instance, If the text contains "1. Andrew is a student at XYZ University who graduated in 2020 ."
For the above text, I require my answer to be "Student1: Andrew, Graduation year: 2020, University: XYZ". Likewise, I need to verify for n number of students and store the results of n number of students. I just know the basics here where I can open the file in different formats such as read, write...So, I am confused about how to proceed to the next step.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have any control over the content/format of the text file you're reading from?  How uniform are the records in the text file?  (Is this an NLP task?)  To get help with your specific task, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes sample data plus the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you might want to look into `json` instead, as it's a bit easier to work with.

```py
import json

# writing to a json file

data = {"andrew": {"university": "XYZ", "graduation": 2020}}

with open("students.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # kwargs for beautification


# reading from a json file

with open("students.json", "r") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

print(data)
print(data["andrew"])
print(data["andrew"]["university"])

# output:
# {'andrew': {'university': 'XYZ', 'graduation': 2020}}
# {'university': 'XYZ', 'graduation': 2020}
# XYZ

# what the file will look like:
{
    "andrew": {
        "graduation": 2020,
        "university": "XYZ"
    }
}
```

A json object behaves exactly like a dictionary - key, value pairs. This will help to navigate and search for/save specific data.

If you'd like to get the number of students, you can do `len(data.keys())` if you have the file structure as is in the example.

---

**References:**

- [File context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)
- [Working with dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) - For saving dictionary objects
- [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) - For loading in dictionary objects

Comment: Is it possible to read from the text file Instead of json format and also here since it is one student we can write in json format and reading what if n number of students will it be more complex or no? BTW the code that you proposed worked... Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! And yeah, it's perfectly valid to work with text files, but you'll need to stick to a consistent format to receive consistent results (i.e. same sentence structure/same num of words per line). I'll edit my answer to include working with text files and also adding more students to a json.